# Remove hover state on click (not working on phones)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a button that performs an ajax action on click (no reload)

On my desktop, when I click the button, the button returns to default style state (when not hovering)

But on phones.. It will **stay in hover style**, even if I click somewhere else

I have tried off("hover") and unbind("mouseover mouseleave mouseenter mousein mouseout hover")

Also tried setting an :active state in css, and creating a classname for the "not-hovered" state, and changing to that on click in jquery

No effect (on any phone)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some example of exactly what are you trying? A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

try making something like this:

```
$('#element').on(click, function{
    this.toggleClass('selected unselected')
});
```

selected and unselected are styles you must add to you CSS, if doesnt overwrite the existing styles add !important at the end of the elements in the style class you are changing for the browser to force them.

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: "Also tried creating a classname for the "not-hovered" state", but thanks

Comment: Try to pass the CSS :hover state only to the desktop version of the site. Mobile browsers do not have hover, so you have not to declare in the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution in all the cases the mobile version do not need the CSS hover state.

First of all, detect if the browser is desktop or mobile (or is touch) via JS / jQuery. Then, add a 'desktop-version' CSS class to the 'body' tag, and set all the ':hover' pseudoclads CSS rules only to the 'desktop-version' anchors / selectors that have a JS function binded to them.

Doing so, they won't have actually no 'hover' state to get stuck with.